# Illustrator script: How to print layers name?

Tags: javascript, svg, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm working with an SVG map in Illustrator.
Each constituency of the map is a layer with its own name.

I would like to print the name of each layer of the map so I can identify each layer when needed.

I wrote this ai script

```
print(document.activeLayer.name);
var layer = new Layer();
layer.name = 'A new layer';
layer.activate();
print(document.activeLayer.name); 
print(document.layers.length);
```

but an "Error 24: print is not a funciton. Line 1". I can't understand how to fix the error.
Has anyone idea of how to make this script work?

Thanks,
Daniele

Comment: `print()` isn't defined in the Illustrator JS API. Use `$.writeln()` instead

Answer (score 1):

if are you referring to "printing to the console", for debugging or otherwise, try...

```
console.println(document.activeLayer.name);
```

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat thanks for this! It was really help full and at the end I was able to print the names. It was difficult because I had to print 650 of them but this saved me quite a bit of time: https://i.imgur.com/OdMdSdm.png

Answer (score 1):

For debugging in extended toolkit and to print the layer name you can use

```
$.writeln(docment.activeLayer.name);
```

OR

```
 $.write(docment.activeLayer.name);
```